# FLEX: how can I get the width of my linkButton object?

Tags: apache-flex

How can I get the width of my LinkButton object ?

myLinkButton = new LinkButton();
myLinkButton.label = "blabla";
myLinkButton.setStyle("fontSize", 24);

myContainer.addChild(myLinkButton); 
trace (myContainer.width); //this doesn't work because I haven't directly set the attribute

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what does that `trace()` show? Is it `null` or `undefined` or `NaN` or simply a wrong value?

Then, there are several ways I can think of how you could get around this problem:

- Try using `getBounds()` or `getRect()`. These methods return a `Rectangle` object working as the `DisplayObject`'s bounding box (including all coordinates and dimensions). Sometimes Flex behaves a bit weird and returns wrong/off results for the coordinates or dimensions of objects.
- Try experimenting with `validateSize()` and/or `measuredWidth`. Perhaps you're trying to access the `width` property too soon so that Flex cannot do the measuring/layouting in time.
- Similar idea: what happens if you use `myContainer.callLater(trace, [myContainer.width]);` (assuming your `myContainer` inherits from `UIComponent`)? If you do get a valid result using `callLater()` but not when accessing `width` directly then Flex just hasn't had a chance to layout and update the container.
- You could also try using [this method](http://www.moock.org/blog/archives/000292.html), which creates a Bitmap from the object and returns the Bitmap's `height`/`width`. This is especially useful if you have components with `visible = false` in your container, because Flex doesn't handle invisible components well in that regard.
- Finally, you could try accessing `$width` in the `mx_internal` namespace and check that property's value. However, using `mx_internal` is sort of a very ugly hack because these properties and methods weren't meant for external use and are subject to change any time (so your component could stop working when a new version is released) - so use with caution.